# What went wrong in the solution of this PDE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve the Fokker Plank equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial S}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial x^2}~.
\end{equation}
This describes trajectories of particles in a random walk. If the starting point of the random walk is at $S_0=0$ and $x_0=x(S_0)=1$, then the boundary conditions for $P(x,S)$ are $P(x_0,S_0)=\delta(x_0)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta function. Another boundary condition is $P(x_c, S)=0$ where $x_c\equiv 1-\alpha S$ is a critical value of $x$, and $\alpha>0$ is a fixed parameter. To solve this equation I let $\gamma\equiv x_c-x$, and carry out Fourier transform of $P$, so that
$$\tilde{P}(\omega, S)=\int \mathrm{d}\gamma\, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\omega\gamma}P(\gamma, S)~,$$
which upon using in the Fokker plank equation (first equation) gives
$$\frac{\partial\tilde{P}}{\partial S}=-\frac{\omega^2}{2}\tilde{P}~,$$
and has a solution
$$\tilde{P}(\omega, S)=c(\omega)\exp\left(-\frac{\omega^2}{2}S\right).$$
The condition that at $\gamma=0 (\delta=\delta_c)$, $P$ vanishes guarentees that $c(\omega)$ is an odd function. Thus, transforming back, I have
$$P(x, S)=\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega\,c(\omega)\sin(\omega\gamma)\exp\left(-\frac{\omega^2}{2}S\right)~,$$
which upon using th boundary condition $P(x_0,S_0)=\delta(x_0)$ immediately gives
$$c(\omega)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(\omega\gamma_0)~,$$
where $\gamma_0=x_0-x_c$. Finally I have 
$$P(x, S)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{d}\omega\,\sin(\omega\gamma_0)\sin(\omega\gamma)\exp\left(-\frac{\omega^2}{2}S\right)~, $$
which gives
$$P(x, S)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi S}}\left[\exp\left(-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2S}\right)-\exp\left(-\frac{[2(x_c-1)-(x-1)]^2}{2S}\right)\right].$$

I have a problem here. If I substitute this expression for $P(x, S)$ in the original PDE, the left hand side is not equal to right hand side unless $x_c$ is independent of $S$. In my case $x_c=1-\alpha S$, so is dependent on $S$. Any idea where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: When you go from the third to the fourth line, don't you need to include a term for some arbitrary function of $x$? $P$ depends on both $x$ and $S$, and yet your solution doesn't show this.

Comment: I am in Fourier space, so instead of $x$, I have $\omega$. Inverse Fourier transform will take me from $\omega$ to $x$, and I have down this later.

Comment: What are the conditions you want to impose? $P(x_0,S_0) = \delta(x_0)$ makes little sense as written, do you mean $P(x,S_0) = \delta(x-x_0)$ instead? You seem to try to solve the equation here by imposing both this initial condition *and* the given boundary condition? (this would be impossible as the solution without imposing this BC is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(S-S_0)}}e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2(S-S_0)}}$ which does not satisfy the BC).